# Is it possible to include .html tags in a realhttp setContent statment?

Tags: python, html, server

I am doing a Packet Tracer project with an SCB acting as a server and sending .html files to a browser. One of these pages needs to display dynamic text based on some of my python variables, as well as have a hard coded link to another page.
[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PajN.png)

The first two lines of dynamic text can be passed using setContent, where the text that is being sent is the value of a python variable. But if I use the same method to pass the line with the link it prints the  tag as plain text.
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFn2.png)

```
link_message = 'Click <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8765/status">here</a> to enable/disable the alarm'
reply_message = '{} \n{}\n\n{}'.format(alarm_system.lcd_line1, alarm_system.lcd_line2, link_message)
reply.setContent(reply_message)
```

The other possibility is hard-coding the last line in an html document and use sendFile, to make the last line display with the link, but I am unsure of how I can pass the python varibales to the html document to craete the first two lines.
What would be the best way to do this?

I have tied searching for ways to make html read  as a tag instead of plain text, but I have not had any luck. I have also tried to hard-code the line with the link in an html file but this seems to prevent me from adding the first two lines with set content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the setContentType command to send the data as html code, rather than palin text. This allows the html to recognize tags, and the link inside the  tag displays correctly.

The line 'reply.setContentType("text/html")' should go before reply.setContent

```
link_message = 'Click <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8765/status"> here</a> to enable/disable the alarm'
reply_message = '{} <br>{}<br><br>{}'.format(alarm_system.lcd_line1, alarm_system.lcd_line2, link_message)
reply.setContentType("text/html")
reply.setContent(reply_message)
```